# Wordpress rss feed as post type with image/permalink

Tags: wordpress, rss

I have a friend who writes to a couple of different blogs and wants to pull stories from one that isn't so popular, onto his main blog with an rss feed and display an image from it too (since rss feeds have images, sometimes).

Displaying the rss feeds shouldn't be too hard, it's making them a custom post type that seems more difficult to me.

If anyone has any ideas, shoot.

EDIT:-
Does anyone know how to get an external rss feed to appear as a custom post type in wordpress?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way may be to use Wordpress' own `fetch_feed` function:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/fetch_feed

A quick example (assuming you've already set up your custom post type):

```
function import_feed_items()
{
  $feed = fetch_feed('http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/uk/rss.xml');

  if( !is_wp_error($feed) )
  {

    if( $last_import = get_option('last_import') )
    {
      $last_import_time = $last_import;
    } else {
      $last_import_time = false;
    }

    $items = $feed->get_items();
    $latest_item_time = false;

    foreach ( $items as $item )
    {

      $item_date = $item->get_date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
      if( $last_import_time && ($last_import_time >= strtotime($item_date)) )
      {
        continue;
      }

      $post = array(
        'post_content'   => $item->get_content(),
        'post_date'      => $item_date,
        'post_title'     => $item->get_title(),
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'post_type'      => 'custom_post_type'
      );
      wp_insert_post($post);

      if( strtotime($item_date) > $latest_item_time )
      {
        $latest_item_time = strtotime($item_date);
      }

    }

    if( false !== $latest_item_time )
    {
      update_option('last_import', $latest_item_time);
    }

  }
  else
  {
    echo $feed->get_error_message();
  }
}
add_action('wp', 'import_feed_items');
```

If there is an image tag in the content you could use php's DomDocument class to grab the url and upload it to your server so you can set it as the featured image.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail

**Edit**

corrected the timestamp check. This updated example uses the 'wp' hook to run so you can see the results quicker. It would be preferable to set this as a cron task. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't do anything, changed 'your_custom_post_type' to mine and it doesn't output anything. (My understanding of php as a language is not great)

Comment: This is meant to import the rss entries as posts. Have you checked the admin to see if this happened?

Comment: Yup, nothing was imported, put that code in my functions.php.

Comment: Sorry andy, I messed up the date checking. I've updated the example and tested that it works.

Comment: Ah that works.
How do you set how often it checks/publishes them and pull the image from the rss feed?

Comment: Have a look at [wp_schedule_event](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event) to set the interval. Use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) to grab the image and save it to your server.

Answer (score 1):

The [Feed to Post](http://www.wprssaggregator.com/extension/feed-to-post/) plugin is the perfect solution for importing multiple RSS items into your WordPress blog, you can even store them as posts or custom post types.

http://www.wprssaggregator.com/extension/feed-to-post/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't know a way off hand, but have you looked at modifying a plugin? There are tons of content curation plugins around (feedwordpress, autoblog, etc.). You could probably find the `wp_insert_post()` line somewhere and modify it to include your custom post type/taxonomies.

**EDIT**
Jumped into the plugin (feedwordpress) myself, and all the `insert_post` stuff is in `syndicatedpost.class.php` - the main `wp_insert_post()` on line 1538

**EDIT** if you fancy a giggle while reading throught that plugin code, you'll find many an instance of the *f word*... haha

Comment: Haha, I downloaded feedwordpress and all I can say is holy moly, that's a lot of source code to trudge through to do something that should be relatively simple.

It looks like a good starting point though, so off to trudge I go...

Answer (score 0):

Hey why dont you try this http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/display-latest-rss-feeds/
It would pull rss feeds from any account and display it to your blog. Unfortunately it wont display images just the rss feeds title and its permalink to the original blog but you can easily modify the source code if you want.